# SpringMVC 3 and Tiles 2 Localization of Page Title

Tags: java, apache, spring, tiles

I have a project setup using Spring 3, Apache Tiles 2 and Maven.
Before I implement Tiles I was using the messages.properties file to dynamically populate the titles for a webpage (The part that appears between the head and title tags). The reason for this was to allow localization in the future. However since I've integrated tiles, the tiles.xml file seems to control the titles for my page.

Is there a way to change this so the page title comes from messages.properties for each jsp I use as the body of a page?

tiles.xml is:

```
 <definition name="base.definition" template="/WEB-INF/views/layouts/layout.jsp">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/views/includes/header.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="menu" value="/WEB-INF/views/includes/menu.jsp" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/views/includes/footer.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="Welcome from Tile" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
</definition>

<definition name="new-deal-input" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="New Deal" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/new-deal-input.jsp" />
</definition>
```

Where you see "Welcome from Tile" or "New Deal" as the title I would rather that this message comes from a messages.properties. I've tried putting the message in the title tags on the "body" page to no avail.

The project is setup on GitHub, you can take a look at this URL: [Group-Deal-Clone](https://github.com/atgheb/Group-Deal-Clone)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can put springs message key to tiles title attribute.

```
<definition name="home" extends="base.definition">
    <put-attribute name="title" value="message.key.welcome.text" />
    <put-attribute name="body" value="/WEB-INF/views/home.jsp" />
</definition>
```

and use it in jsp something like this

```
     <c:set var="titleKey">
        <tiles:insertAttribute name="title" ignore="true" />
    </c:set>
    <title><spring:message key="${titleKey}" /></title>
```

I don't have right now tiles + spring project on hands so I can't check is syntax 100% correct but I have use this approach before.

And of course you could do something like this to get per page title

```
<title><spring:message key="welcome.${titleKey}"/></title>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reponse but your approach wont work for a simple reason that tiles inserts header information separately. Using this approach results in 2 <title> and <head> tags on the page. What i need is for some way to replace the tile attribute title value in the JSP or to dynamically define it in the tiles.xml.

Comment: Sorry, you are absolutely correct, my mistake was that I was concentrating on the jsp for the body where as the code you gave me works when put in the layout jsp.

Answer (score 18):

Another variant, without c:set:

in tiles-defs.xml:

```
<definition name="index" template="/WEB-INF/tiles/base.jsp">
  <put-attribute name="title" value="home.title"/>
  <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/includes/iheader.jsp"/>
  ...
</definition>
```

in base.jsp:

```
<head>
 <tiles:importAttribute name="title" />
 <title><spring:message code="${title}"></spring:message></title>
</head>
```

in messages.properties:

```
home.title=Homepage title
```